# How to move Azure APIM APIs from one APIM to another

Tags: azure-api-management

I have two Azure APIM instances, one is a development sub, the other is for Production.

I had hoped to leverage the GIT Repository configuration to pull down changes from DEV, copy them manually over to my PRD folder and then push them up into PRD.

Doing this wasn't as clean as I had hoped and generated some errors.

Is there a prescribed way that I can migrate code from one tenant to the other?

The only other option I am seeing is the REST API?

Comment: You can use the [Azure API Management DevOps Resource Kit](https://github.com/Azure/azure-api-management-devops-resource-kit)

Answer (score 1):

As @*MarkusMeyer* suggested, you have to use the Extractor Tool from the Azure APIM DevOps Resource Kit to produce the ARM templates for the bunch of APIs and Policies you have created and defined and then you have to use the REST API or PowerShell Script for moving as a batch, more info on #[1179492](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1179492/migrate-apis-from-apim-to-another-apim-instance-as) by @*MuthuKumaranMurugaachari-MSFT*.

Following the Microsoft Generic [Article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/51360.azure-how-to-move-resources-between-subscriptions-under-different-tenants.aspx), another workaround is you should have the 3 Subscriptions Where 2 from the same tenant.

- Assume S1, S2 should from the Source Tenant and S3 from the Destination Tenant.
- Move all the required resources such as APIM Instances and its dependencies (if any) from the current Subscription (assume S1) to the temporary Subscription S2 under the Same Tenant.
- After Successful moving of the resources to S2 Subscription, change its tenant to the destination tenant:
  [image]
- And then move resources from S2 (Destination Tenant) to the S3 Subscription in the Same destination Tenant.